# React State not updating? Will not render cards? Backend is fine! Can anyone figure this out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

The problem I am having is that I am trying to render these cards for posts from Reddit into my application based off if there is anything in the "content" state.

For some reason, the backend is totally okay, and I had this working in a single page context, but I cannot get <Card/> to render and when I hit the search button even though I can log the content array ANYWHERE, I cannot generate cards and it says type error undefined. How can I fix this?

[Error image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrAMV.png)

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import './Search.css'
    import { PostContainer } from '../../components/PostContainer'
    import ContentContainer from '../../components/ContentContainer'
    import Card from '../../components/Card'
    import { SearchContainer, SearchInput, SearchBtn } from "../../components/SearchContainer";
    import { Col, Row, Container } from "../../components/Grid";
    import Snoo from "../../utils/Snoo";
    import API from "../../utils/API";


    class Home extends Component {
      // constructor(props) {
      //   super(props);

      //   // Assign state itself, and a default value for items
      //   this.state = {
      //     content: [],
      //     search: "",
      //   };
      // }
      state = {
        content: [],
        search: "",
      };



      createPosts = (data) => {
        // this.setState({content: subData})
        // console.log(subData)
        // this.setState({
        //   content: res
        // });
        this.setState({ content: data })
        console.log(this.state.content)
      }

      handleInputChange = event => {
        const { id, value } = event.target;
        this.setState({
          [id]: value
        });
      };

      handleSearch = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.search) {
          Snoo.snooScrape(this.state.search)
            .then(res => {
              let data = res
              this.createPosts(data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <Container fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col size="md-12">
                <SearchContainer>
                  <form>
                    <SearchInput
                      value={this.state.search}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      name="search"
                      id='search'
                      placeholder="Search Subreddits"
                    />
                    <SearchBtn
                      onClick={this.handleSearch}
                    >
                      Search
                      </SearchBtn>

                  </form>
                </SearchContainer>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col size="md-12">
                {this.state.content.length ? (
                  <PostContainer>
                    {this.state.content.map(post => (
                      <Card
                        title={post.title}
                      >

                      </Card>
                    ))}
                  </PostContainer>) : (
                    <div>nnanaaahghhhhh</div>
                  )
                }
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Home;
```

Here is my card component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Card.css'

export const Card = props => {
      return (
            <div className='post-card' id={this.props.isSaved}>

                  <p className='post-title'>{props.title}</p>

                  <p className='post-author'>{props.author}</p>
                  {props.children}
            </div>
      )
}
```

And its index.js:

```
export {default} from "./Card.js"
```

And my API response is simply an array of 25 large JSON objects. I am using snoowrap/axios. Mongo is going to get thrown in here too, but it's not in use at the moment. I am able to manipulate the response on the client side, but it just doesn't seem to be updating state for "content". I can log it out in the console as if it has, but it seems like it is trying to create the cards before it has the new state or something.

The conditional rendering also works! It can tell there isn't ANYTHING in the this.state.content array, @ this.state.content.length, but they're all null for some reason when they get there.

I am COMPLETLELY stumped :/

SECOND EDIT:

Here is my API request

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {

  snooScrape: function (searchQuery) {
    return axios.get("/api/snoo/" + searchQuery).then(res => {
      let response = res.data
      return response

    })
  }
}
```

And the response:

[JSON response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEk2f.png)

And on the front end:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1gqe.png).

I can even this.setState({content:subData}) successfully and log it. It seems to be an asynchronous issue of some kind :/

Comment: You need to refine this question a bit. It's too much all at once.

Comment: Are your search functions bound to the class?

Comment: no, i dont believe i explicitly bound them. im just learning react. i added more info to the post above!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from the Card component. Please log the API response and also place it in here.

Comment: i adedmore info to the post! and the code for the card component and how i exported it

Answer (score 0):

From a first sight it seems like your page shouldn't be throwing an error because you initialized `this.state.content` with an empty array.

But the errors are suggesting that your `this.state.content`'s children are undefined. Something's off when you're updating the state with your API callback. Please supply the question with the API response.